# I want to send push notification with api

Tags: wordpress, api, push-notification, wordpress-rest-api, woocommerce-rest-api

Everyone, I want to send push notification of wordpress random post and schedule it minutely. I wrote the code. But Not working. Can You find where is wrong or recommend any correction?

````
if ( ! wp_next_scheduled( 'send_notification' ) ) {
  wp_schedule_event( time(), 'minutely', 'send_notification' );

function send_notification (  ) {
      $end_point   = 'https://api.webpushr.com/v1/notification/send/segment';
    $args = array(
  'posts_per_page' => 1,
  'orderby' => 'rand',
);
$random_post = get_posts( $args );
  $body = array(
            'title'      => $random_post[0]->post_title,
            'message'    => 'check out now',
            'target_url' =>get_permalink( $random_post[0]->ID ),
             //'image'   => get_the_post_thumbnail_url($product->get_id()),
               // 'icon'=>  get_the_post_thumbnail_url($product->get_id()),  
             'segment'      => array(489294 ), //required
        );
        $response = wp_remote_post( $end_point, array(
            'method'      => 'POST',
            'timeout'     => 45,
            'headers' => array(
                'Content-Type' => 'Application/Json',
                'webpushrKey' => 'XXXXXXXXX',
                'webpushrAuthToken' => '29009'
            ),
            'body' => json_encode($body), //replace it with $body if a array body is expected by the api.
        ));
     
        if ( is_wp_error( $response ) ) {
            $error_message = $response->get_error_message();
            //Something went wrong
        } else {
            //Success. Store or output $response as you want.
            //use: wp_remote_retrieve_body( $response ) to get response body
        }
             
    }
}

add_action( 'send_notification', 'send_notification' ); ```
````

Comment: are you getting an error?